# How do I set nuxt-link's active-class for links with parameters?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

My code is this.
However, in this code, "/" does not become active-class when `domain.com/?standalone=true`.

```vue
<nuxt-link to="/" class="navBotton" exact-active-class="active" ><span>Home</span>
</nuxt-link>
<nuxt-link to="/post" class="navBotton" active-class="active" ><span>Post</span>
</nuxt-link>
<nuxt-link to="/about" class="navBotton" active-class="active" ><span>About</span>
</nuxt-link>
```

How do I fix it?

When I remove exact, it becomes active-class on all pages.

---

Thank you for some answers.

I found a way to activate when "/" regardless of parameter.
This is the code.

```vue
<nuxt-link
    to="/"
    class="navBotton home"
    :class="{'active': isRouteActive }"
    exact-active-class="active"
>
```

```vue
computed: {
    isRouteActive: function() {
      if (this.$nuxt.$route.path=="/") {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm sure you mean `class="navButton"` not `navBotton`

Answer (score 27):

in nuxt configuration file usually called `nuxt.config.js` there is a property of the object called router:

```js
router: {
    linkActiveClass: 'your-custom-active-link',
    linkExactActiveClass: 'your-custom-exact-active-link',
  }
```

Then in your css:

```css
.your-custom-active-link {
  /* styles here */
}
.your-custom-exact-active-link {
  /* styles here */
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is for a global configuration. I have many menus in my website with different backgrounds. I can't use this. What is another alternative?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. Worked around it like this:

```
<b-link :class="{'nuxt-link-active': isRouteActive(id) }" :to="id + '?someParams=true'">
```

Method:

```vue
methods: {
    isRouteActive(id) {
      if (this.$route.path.includes(id)) {
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    },
    log() {
      console.log(this.categories)
    }
}
```

However, I wonder if there is a native way to do this...

Comment: Wonderful! This is even better than the global router config, because I can do custom match here... Also, my app has multiple links/menus and the active class changes according to the link. Global config was not for me.  +1 from my side.

p.s. for nuxt 3, use `const router = useRouter();` and `router.currentRoute.value.path`.

Answer (score 3):

for nuxtjs 3, you should configure it like this;

```
router: {
    options: {
      linkActiveClass: "active",
      linkExactActiveClass: "exact-active"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Stylize the class `.nuxt-link-active` and automatically will work.

Reference: https://nuxtjs.org/examples/routing/active-link-classes/

Comment: yes in nuxt3 .router-link-active and .router-link-exact-active is generated automatically when you use the NuxtLink so you can stylize the css to suit your needs.